# React-native: multiple style props in styled-component and typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

I am using React-native typescript for my app. I am really new in React-native. lots of syntax are new to me. For styling I am using [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/). I have created global button components. So, I can use it in different components. I want to create conditional size and color of buttons. So, I can manipulate the size and color from parent components. I can do two conditional style props. But i don't know how to do multiple conditions in React-native.

**This is my Button component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components/native';


export interface IButton {
  appearance?: "primary" | "secondary" | "dark" | "light";
  children?: string | JSX.Element;
  size?: "small" | "medium" | "big";
  className?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  loading?: boolean;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  onPress?: () => void;
}

const Button = ({ appearance, children, size, disabled, loading, style, onPress, className }: IButton) => {
  return (
    <ButtonContainer
      className={className}
      onPress={onPress}
      disabled={disabled}
      style={
        disabled ?
          { ...style, "opacity": 0.5, "pointerEvents": `none` } :
          loading ?
            { ...style, "pointerEvents": `none` } :
            style
      }
    >
      {loading ? <Label>loading...</Label> : <Label>{children} </Label>}
    </ButtonContainer>
  );
};


const Label = styled.Text`
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px;
`

const ButtonContainer = styled.TouchableHighlight<
  {
    appearance: IButton["appearance"]; // this is my typescript props I don't know how to connect them with my Button styling.
  }
  >`
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
 background-color:${props => props.primary ? "gray" : "blue"} //
`

export default Button;
```

**This is my the parent component where I am using my button component.**

```
<Button
    size="medium" //this is does not work because I did not style yet
    onPress={() => console.log('hello')}

  >
    click me 
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`style={[disabled && { opacity: 0.5, pointerEvents: "none" }, loading && { pointerEvents: "none" }, style ]}`

P.S. You should stick to the basic first before diving into advanced topics such as Typescript and styled components

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but my disabled button and loading logic works fine. i don't have issue with it.